# Is it possible to run Spring Boot REST API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to run a Spring Boot REST API service on top of Node.js instead of Tomcat,
or if not Node.js which are the other possible servers on which we can run our Spring Boot REST Application.

Please help me figure it out.

Comment: When you say 'Node.js instead of Tomcat', what are you exactly trying to say? I mean, Node.js is a Javascript runtime environment, not a server. Okay, it has the built-in http module which can starts an instance of the http server by typing `node <your-app>.js` in the CLI. But actually, I didn't understood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NodeJs` is a server to run `Javascript` code. It can not run a Java web application, which needs a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) to be run into a JVM. Before you ask, no, NodeJS can not run a JVM. Is is just not made for that. To understand what I mean, it's like wanting a car to run with a outboard engine... Definitly not possible.

So NO, you can't run your Spring Boot REST Application on the top of NodeJs server.

If you don't want to use a Tomcat, then there is other options for you:
https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/04/top-10-open-source-java-and-javaee-application-servers/